# How to download pdf file from database using asp gridview link button

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

1. I have stored binary data into a db.
2. When I'm fetching and trying to download same pdf file I'm unable to do it.
3. Below is my code snippet:

   ```
   protected void grdDownload_Command(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {

       if (e.CommandName == "Download")
       {
           int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

           DataTable dtFilterData = `enter code here`GetPDFFile("D", Convert.ToString(index));

           Response.Clear();
           Response.Buffer = true;
           Response.ContentType = dtFilterData.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
           Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dtFilterData.Rows[0]["Name_File"].ToString()); // to open file prompt Box open or Save file  
           Response.Charset = "";
           Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
           Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dtFilterData.Rows[0]["FileData"]);
           Response.End();  

       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Finally i have resolved this issue. We need to add update panel for link button inside the Item template.
2. Adding Postback Trigger has resolved this issue.